# vscode JuanBlanco Solidity extension makes autoclosingQuote not working

Tags: solidity

When I sellect word `contract` and type `"`,
I was expecting it to be `"contract"` but it rather replaces it to just `"`.
I figured out that was due to JuanBlanco.Solidity extension (it works fine when I disable it).

Someone knows how to deal with this issue?